# Two-column layout in Bootstrap (max-width and fixed size columns)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I achieve the following two-column layout in Bootstrap?

- Column 1: Width adjusts to available size, between a min and max width
- Column 2: Fixed size width

For example, if I have:

- Column 1 min width: 300px
- Column 1 max width: 800px
- Column 2 width: 400px

In a resolution with a width of 800px available, I would expect both columns to be 400px wide.
In a resolution with 2000px available, I would expect the first column to be 800px, the second column to be 400px, and there would be 800px of blank space at the right of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard because bootstrap is usefull for responsive, non static...

Can it be correct with this way : http://bootply.com/98214

**html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="col1" class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">coco 1</div>
  <div id="col2" class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">coco 2</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#col1{
  background:green;
  max-width:800px !important;
}

#col2{
  background:yellow;
  max-width:400px !important;
}
```

You shouldn't use min-width because in case of extra small device, it won't have a good render